# What is difference in 2 ways transfer data to fragment from activity using getArgument() and getActivity.getXXX()

Tags: android

I wonder the difference between two ways of transfering data from activity to fragment.

One is using getArgument() and setArgument(). I can transfer data using these methods at Fragment's contruction time.

Another is using getActivity() method. Like this way

```
((HostActivity)getActivity()).getXXX()
```

After declaring getter method of data Fragment may use, call this method in fragment through getActivity() and Type casting.

I think second one is easier and convenient. Because get/setArgument() can be called only Fragment's contruction time.

So, How to apply these 2 way to sending and getting data between Activity and Fragment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> A Fragment represents a behavior or a portion of user interface in an
>   Activity. You can combine multiple fragments in a single activity to
>   build a multi-pane UI and **reuse a fragment in multiple activities**.

Because fragment can reuse in multiple activity, if you use getActivity() with type casting, you must check *instanceOf* activity before call method. And each of activity use that fragment, you must implement method *getXXX()*. 
Use **newInstance** method in fragment, you only pass require parameter for it.

If you create fragment for individual activity, you can apply 2 ways transfer data.

Answer (score 0):

The fragment has an independent lifecycle from activity with specific threads, functions and handlers. So you can use getters/setters Activity variables like a global variables and bundle data (arguments) to independent fragment variables.